# How regex.test() have an impact on string.matchAll()?

Tags: javascript, regex

The goal of the code below is to get all parts of the string with a special treatment for text between `* ... *` (ie: emboldening).

```js
const regex = new RegExp("([^\\*]*)*\\*([^\\*]+)\\*", "g");
const string = '*A B C*D E F*G H I*J K L*M N O*P Q R*S T U*';

const matches = string.matchAll(regex);
result = 'Result => ';
for (const match of matches) {
  result += (match[1] ? match[1] : '') + (match[2] ? '<b>'+match[2]+'</b>' : '');
}
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = result;
```

Actually, that works fine.
But if I had a simple test on the regex (`regex.test(string)`) before doing all the `matchAll` process, the result returned is not the same (skipping the begining of the string) :

```js
const regex = new RegExp("([^\\*]*)*\\*([^\\*]+)\\*", "g");
const string = '*A B C*D E F*G H I*J K L*M N O*P Q R*S T U*';

if (regex.test(string)) {
  const matches = string.matchAll(regex);
  result = 'Result => ';
  for (const match of matches) {
    result += (match[1] ? match[1] : '') + (match[2] ? '<b>'+match[2]+'</b>' : '');
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = result;
}
```

I didn't found any documentation or clue on this weirdness... Is this a bug ? Or a trap and I fell inside ? Someone have any explanation ?

Comment: Because it moves the RegExp index due to the `g` flag. BTW, it seems `string.replace(/\*([^*]+)\*/g, '<b>$1</b>')` would be enough.

Comment: Global regular expressions are stateful. That's why using them more than once will cause a difference.